# Solr - (RE)-Query Solr on the basis of data fetched in some fields from the 1st query

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I am using `Solr 4.0`. I have approximately 1+ million records.

The best way to explain my question is through an example -

Consider I have two fields name and type (type is a facet) in my schema.

I have 4 records -

```
    name                  type
stackoverflow        Knowledge markets
meta stackoverflow   Knowledge markets
ask ubuntu           Knowledge markets
programmers          Q&A for programmers
```

Now when `Solr` is queried for `q=name:*stack*` the first 2 records come up with `facet` of `type` having `Knowledge markets` count 2.

I then have to get the highest count in the facet, in this case its `Knowledge markets`, and query `Solr`again `q=type:Knowledge markets`, ignore the records which came up in the first query. So that `ask ubuntu`is displayed in the recommendations section.

**Is it possible to do the above things in 1 query?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if this is possible in only a single query as you need to determine the faceting results before you can query for it. One possible option would be to perform a facet only query initially to get just the highest facet count and then run the secondary query.

So first query for `&q=name:*stack*&rows=0&facet.field=type&facet.limit=1` where the `rows=0` option will not return any search results only the facets and `facet.limit=1` will only return one result, which should be the highest value.

Then you can run your second query to get all the names associated with the selected type.

**Edit:**
After further clarification from Junaid it turns out that the original results are still needed, so what I listed above will only work for getting the facet results. The following should work:
First get data of `q=name:*stack*` and get the highest facet value. Then run another query like `q=type:Knowledge markets AND -name:*stack*` to get the type result values for the recommendations but filter out the name values from the first query.

Comment: Thank you Paige. The issue in the approach suggested by you is the "real" search result is lost i.e. the user should be shown stackoverflow and meta stackoverflow as the main search result and the output (ask ubuntu) on the basis the facet output (Knowledge markets) of the first query should be shown in the secondary search result as "recommendation" for example.

Comment: OK. I see now. Sorry I missed that. Unfortunately, I cannot think of a way to get all of this information in a single query. B/c again, you need to run the first query to figure out the type with the highest count prior to searching for all records with that type.

Comment: So the only solution is first get data of q=name:*stack* and get the highest facet value. Then run another query like q=type:Knowledge markets AND -name:*stack*. Right?